# Unkown symbol in schematic

Tags: schematics

I researched but I could not find anything like this, should I be worried about what is this symbol?

This schematic is a part of a board I'm working on, the part that regulates voltage from 2.6 - 4.2 Vin to 3.3 Vout.
I got it from WEBENCH, and as stated there:

1. The TPS61022 Device will operate in Pass-Through mode when Vin is greater than Vout. In Pass-Through mode, Vout is not regulated to
   the set Vout, instead Vout is Vin with the drop across the FET?s on-resistance and the DCR of the inductor. 2. This is a Boost Converter with
   0.5V ultra-low input voltage. 3. The efficiency validation is done only for FPWM mode. Charts may be inaccurate for AutoMode at light loads and
   hence they are disabled for light loads.

Also on the page, Iout is described simply as Iout operating point.

I don't know which of those infos are relevant here really, but I hope some of it will be, since I have no idea what that symbol means it also does not help me on how to explain my situation much.

If there is more info I could add, I'll be glad to.

[image]

I thought it was some kind of Ampmeter? Is it just to symbolize output? I don't know.

Thanks!

Comment: What is the context for this schematic? Is it a reference design? A schematic for a test fixture used to obtain a graph or numerical figure of merit? Some other context? [Edit] your post to provide this information.

Comment: Almost looks like an oscilloscope display - maybe the user of the circuit is meant to plug a scope in there.  It would NOT be an ammeter. That'd be a short circuit.

Comment: That looks more like a simulation circuit rather than a design schematic. That is more than likely a piecewise linear current source setup to mimic load changes

Comment: Sorry, I added more info to the post.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is a load transient block to assist in testing the stability and capability of the DCDC design

55 seconds into the training video

https://training.ti.com/webenchr-power-designer-simulation-overview?cu=1136926

If you goto the TPS61022 product page ( https://www.ti.com/product/TPS61022# ) there is a WebBench design parameters

Vin  2.7 - 4.35
Vout 5V
Iout 3A

[image]

If you were to put them into WebBench, the model for TPS61022 is on the first page and as you can see it is in the base-model. Why this particular design example includes this? Only TI would be able to say. Maybe there is a selling point associated with this part and large step load changes

[image]

Comment: Oh thanks, It's been a while since I watched that, and I was also not simulating the schematic, why would that appear? Anyway, thanks! Will re-watch some of those videos again.

Comment: It is part of the reference design on WebBench.